# How does the line with two backslashes fool C preprocessor?

Tags: c, haskell, c-preprocessor

I decided to take a look into the source of a standard Haskell module [Data.List](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.3.1.0/docs/src/Data-List.html) an found something interesting. The code is obviously firstly processed by C preprocessor, as a bunch of `#ifdef`s suggest, and only after that is compiled by Haskell compiler. However, C preprocessor is not very friendly to the source code different from C itself, as pointed out in the [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Overview.html#Overview):

> The C preprocessor is intended to be used only with C, C++, and Objective-C source code. In the past, it has been abused as a general text processor. It will choke on input which does not obey C's lexical rules. For example, apostrophes will be interpreted as the beginning of character constants, and cause errors. Also, you cannot rely on it preserving characteristics of the input which are not significant to C-family languages. If a Makefile is preprocessed, all the hard tabs will be removed, and the Makefile will not work.

But somehow Haskell code is still preserved under C preprocessing? Probably this snippet gives a clue:

```
#ifdef __GLASGOW_HASKELL__
import GHC.Num
import GHC.Real
import GHC.List
import GHC.Base
#endif

infix 5 \\ -- comment to fool cpp

-- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- List functions
```

How does this `comment to fool cpp` work? Looks like an interesting hack, but I could not google anything on the topic. In Haskell this line declares an infix operator `\\` with priority 5, and all the text after `--` is ignored. But what does it do with C preprocessor and in which way is it actually "fooled"?

Comment: You did not mention which command have you used for preprocessing your file ?

Comment: @Sabrina This is not "my file", this is the official source of a Haskell module. I didn't preprocessed it and I didn't got your question. I was just interested what is this comment in the source about.

Comment: backslash-newline when it is at the end of the line it is mainly used to join the current line with the following line creating a source logical line. In your example they added a haskell comment so to prevent that from happening. The good thing here is that comment in haskell is different from  C, objective C and C++ ; CPP here is not going to interpret it as comment but as preprocessing tokens. In this case, \\ will be considered as a an escape sequence character and not backslash-newline.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you put simply this:

```
infix 5 \\
```

the C preprocessor issues the following message when the line is at the end of the file:

```
infix 5 \foo.c:8:10: warning: backslash-newline at end of file
```

And if it's not at the end of the file (thanks @commenter), it just "eats" one backslash (to associate it with the following newline) and the output is incorrect on the Haskell side:

```
infix 5 \
```

BUT if you add an Haskell-type comment afterwards, Haskell ignores it (obviously!), and it isn't a problem for the C preprocessor since `\` isn't at the end of the line:

```
infix 5 \\ -- comment
```

cpp issues the exact same text and Haskell can parse the interesting part, stripping the --` comment.

(note that it is never valid C, but the preprocessor doesn't mind)

Note: the problem is similar if you want to end your C/C++ `//` comment line with `\`: you can't without it continuing the comment on the next line: not what you want.

Comment: Okay, but why it says that the backslash-newline is at the end of file? This line is obviously not the end of file.

Comment: @Wolfram you're right, my test was incomplete, edited.

Comment: Ah, got it, it eats backslash because a single backslash is reserved for line gluing, so to make a real backslash at the end of a line we need to escape it. But if the backslash isn't in the end of a line, it is not eaten. Didn't know that, thanks)

Comment: exactly! very refreshing question I have to say :)

Comment: That's why ending C single line comments with ??/ is dangerous as well. It's a trigraph that is replaced with a simple backslash \.

Comment: @Xeneda, I thought trigraphs are not enabled by default in gcc.

Comment: actually you get a warning like this: so no they're not enabled: `trigraph ??/ ignored, use -trigraphs to enable [-Wtrigraphs]`

Comment: trigraph useless feature for you maybe but for some implementations  it is a great feature.

Comment: @Sabrina: that was just my opinion. I'd like to know where it is used

Comment: Oh well, I thought they were enabled by default.
@Jean-FrançoisFabre: Some keyboards (especially older ones) are missing some keys or it is harder to write some signs. For example, the QWERTZ-keyboard used in Austria and in Germany makes it a bit harder to write some signs, e.g. for `^` (xor) you need to type another character after it to be written. `[, ], {, }` are `Alt-Gr`-combinations. I always hit `Alt-Gr` with my right thumb. If you lost your right thumb in an accident or something, you might prefer using trigraphs for those characters.

Comment: ok, now if you lose your thumb or missing keys on keyboard, this isn't good a reason enough to start using those. I can't imagine contributing to a major project (with more than 1 people) using these. Copy/paste of existing symbols is your friend in those cases.

Comment: @Xeneda That's not a valid reason to make your code less readable. Copypasting is tedious, but today one can easily configure automatic replacement of certain combinations by desirable symbols with AutoHotKey (Windows) or AutoKey/xbindkeys/etc. (Linux). Trigraphs are just a legacy, imho.

Comment: I don't use them. I just told @Jean-FrançoisFabre what they **can** be used for. Not when they **should** be used. :)

Comment: For @Jean-FrançoisFabre sthg that he did not used is useless.

Comment: @Sabrina. as I said in a further comment, only my opinion. I've been coding C for more than 25 years and I never got to use that.